# Azure storage - Any timing issues with this code?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am using Azure storage to store and retrieve images. I have this method to save an image (blob):

```
public void SaveBlob(string containerName, string blobName, byte[] blob)
{
    // Retrieve reference to the blob
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = GetContainer(containerName, true).GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(blob, writable: false))
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);
    }
}
```

This is the GetContainer method:

```
    public CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(string containerName, bool createIfNotExist)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(containerName))
            return null;

        // Retrieve a reference to a container. If container doesn't exist, optionally create it.
        CloudBlobContainer container = this._blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
        if (container == null && !createIfNotExist)
            return null;

        // Create the container if it doesn't already exist. It will be private by default.
        container.CreateIfNotExists(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off, null, null);

        return container;
    }
```

What's happening here is that when I attempt to save a blob, I get a reference to a container first. If the container doesn't exist, it is created, and then the blob is saved. Will I run into timing issues here if I have to create the container first and then save a blob to it immediately? My concern is that I might be attempting to save the blob to the container before Azure is finished creating it. Or maybe this isn't an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code, I don't think you will run into any timing issues because `CreateIfNotExists` method is a sync method and will only return when the container is created. Also with Azure Blob Storage (unlike Amazon S3), the method will either create the container immediately or throw an error if it fails to do so (or in other words Azure Storage is `Strongly Consistent`).

Also I think this piece of code is redundant:

```
if (container == null && !createIfNotExist)
            return null;
```

As `container` will never be equal to `null` and thus this `if` condition will never be `true`.

Comment: You said container will never be equal to null. What will it be equal to if the container doesn't yet exist?

Comment: When you call `GetContainerReference`, it does not make a network call to check if the container exists or not. It just creates an instance of `CloudBlobContainer` object. Then you can perform operation on that object and those operations (like `CreateIfNotExists`) will make network calls.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I need to call the Exists method on CloudBlobContainer to see if the container exists.

Comment: I would not recommend that. If there's a possibility that the container may be deleted by some other process, I would just stick with `CreateIfNotExists` call so that before uploading blob, you're always ensured that the container exists. To avoid network call overhead with `CreateIfNotExists` you can separate these two methods and create blob container separately (may be during application startup if the container is common for all users or user registration if the container is specific for a particular user).